# What are the differences between using router from express.js vs filesystem from node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to learn node.js and saw two ways of building an web application both used express as a listener to the website, the difference was one time I used fs for loading files and in the other I used router.
I want to know what are the pros and cons for each one of them? 
In the code you can see an example of the code I have used.

```
Router-code:

const express = require('express');
firstRoute = require('./routes/first');
const app = express();
app.use('/first',firstRoute);


Filesystem-code:
var fs = require('fs');

function getStaticFileContent(response,filepath,contentType){
        fs.readFile(filepath,function(error,data){
            if(error){
                    response.writeHead(500,{'Content-type': 'text/plain'});
                    response.end('500 - Internal Server Error');
            }
            if(data){
                    response.writeHead(200,{'Content-type': 'text/html'});
                    response.end(data);

            }
        });

}
```

Comment: In programming, you can often do the same thing in different ways. _express_ is just a framework that makes easier for you things that you would have code "by hand".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so it is just like a wrapper and using the file system is most likely faster (regard to running time) and we have more control over the system? Or it isn't the case here?

Comment: Like everything, it depends of context. For what it worth, _express_ is designed to be very light and speed should not be a problem. But sure, if you do everything yourself, you'll have de facto more control. Not sure if it is the right choice though.